# Installed BeautifulSoup but still get no module named bs4

Tags: beautifulsoup, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, python-3.5

I'm using a Jupyter notebook, Python 3.5, and a virtual environment.

Within my virtual env I did:

```
(venv) > pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Which seemed to run fine b/c the terminal output was:

```
Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl (86kB)
  100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 297kB/s 
Installing collected packages: BeautifulSoup4
Successfully installed BeautifulSoup4-4.6.0
```

But when I run my Jupyter notebook I get:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5fe69888b1a1> in <module>()
      5 from itertools import groupby
      6 import pickle
----> 7 import bs4
      8 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      9 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

And I can't change the line `import bs4` to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` which I've seen on other SO posts b/c its read-only and I'm not supposed to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3, I think you needed to do

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Just pip install would have been for the Python 2 package.

Other things to check:

First make sure you ran both the BeautifulSoup install in your virtualenv, and the python3 prompt or Jupyter notebook in your virtualenv. If you did the install in  your root environment and the notebook is run in your virtualenv, or vice versa, you might have a mismatch in your site-packages directory.

Ensure that your package indeed installed by typing pip3 list at a command prompt, and noting that it appeared in the list.

Check that you Jupyter notebook is indeed running a Python 3.5 kernel (upper right hand corner of the browser window)

Check that the path where the package is installed is in your sys.path

Open a Python3 prompt or in Jupyter and run

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem b/c I already tried that and got: `Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: I think it installed the wrong( Python2) package. Try removing that and reinstalling with pip3. It's finding the package but it's not importable from a Python 3 virtualenv

Comment: Okay I did `pip uninstall BeautifulSoup4`, `pip3 uninstall BeautifulSoup4`, and `pip3 uninstall bs4`. Then I did `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` which the terminal said `Collecting BeautifulSoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: BeautifulSoup4
Successfully installed BeautifulSoup4-4.6.0` but it's still not working :(

Comment: import bs4 fails still? also from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ? The later should work at least. Also do pip3 list and make sure it really is there in the list of packages. If that fails you may need to install from source with setup.py

Comment: Yeah both `import bs4` and `bs4 import BeautifulSoup` fail when I use `python3` interpreter from the Terminal. What do you mean by doing "pip3 list"? Like what command should I run?

Comment: run "pip3 list' from a command interpreter. this will show a list of all installed packages.

Comment: Yep I see it `beautifulsoup4 (4.6.0)`

Comment: did you by chance have a previous version of beautifulsoup installed before? try pip3 install BeautifulSoup4 --upgrade

Comment: Nopee terminal told me `Requirement already up-to-date: BeautifulSoup4 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`

Comment: It should work. Does it import form a Python 3 command prompt?

Comment: No..tried both `import bs4` and `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` again and same `ImportError: No module named 'bs4'` :(

Comment: One final thing, import sys then print sys.path. Is the location of the package (that /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python‌​3.5/site-packages) in your sys.path? If not you'l need to add it.

Comment: `sys.path` has `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python‌​3.5` so I'm assuming `site-packages` should work

Comment: Altho there is `/Users/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages` so maybe its looking in the wrong site-package?

Comment: Are you sure your virtualenv is active when you install and when you run? Looks like somehow a site-packages mismatch is the cause of the trouble. It's hard to troubleshoot further without duplicating your environment - sorry I could not solve the problem !

Comment: that's okay! i think you're gettin to the bottom of it tho! b/c when I copied and pasted `bs4` folder and `beautifulsoup` folder from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python‌​‌​3.5/site-packages` to `/Users/.../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, that import statement now works. But now I get the same import error on a different package. So it seems like what you're saying is correct. However I am confused b/c on my Terminal I see `(venv) >` so I feel that I should be installing in my `venv` and so im not sure why im not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, bs4 was installed in my virtual environment along with Jupyter Lab. Jupyter would throw the ModuleNotFound Error but if I opened the notebook in Visual Studio Code and chose the .venv as the interpreter, it worked.

I got it to work in Jupyter Lab by uninstalling from the virtual environment and installing with `sudo apt-get install python3-bs4` instead.